# How to handle a LINQ expression that fails if an element is missing

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, generics

I'm a rookie with LINQ to XML and I've got this code that works (most of the time):

```
private long processFile(StreamWriter oWriter, string inFileName)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(inFileName);
        List<DocMetaData> docList =
            (from d in xmlDoc.Descendants("DOCUMENT")
             select new DocMetaData
             {
                 Folder = d.Element("FOLDER").Attribute("name").Value
                 ,
                 File = d.Element("FILE").Attribute("filename").Value
                 ,
                 Comment = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Comment(idmComment)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
                 ,
                 Title = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Title(idmName)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
                 ,
                 DocClass = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Document Class(idmDocType)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
             }
            ).ToList<DocMetaData>();
        OutputListToFile(oWriter, docList);
        return docList.LongCount();
    }
```

This fails on line 117 (the select expression) with:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CBMI.WinFormsUI.GridForm.<processFile>b__3(XElement d) in C:\ProjectsVS2010\CBMI.LatitudePostConverter\CBMI.LatitudePostConverter\CBMI.WinFormsUI\GridForm.cs:line 117
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CBMI.WinFormsUI.GridForm.processFile(StreamWriter oWriter, String inFileName) in C:\ProjectsVS2010\CBMI.LatitudePostConverter\CBMI.LatitudePostConverter\CBMI.WinFormsUI\GridForm.cs:line 115
   at CBMI.WinFormsUI.GridForm.btnProcess_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\ProjectsVS2010\CBMI.LatitudePostConverter\CBMI.LatitudePostConverter\CBMI.WinFormsUI\GridForm.cs:line 85
```

The data is well-formed XML. There are many `<DOCUMENT>` nodes in this given XML file and most but not all, `<DOCUMENT>` nodes contain a `<FOLDER>` node. I discovered this by brute force opening the XML file with VStudio 2010 and using Find command which gives counts of matching lines.

Is there a way I can improve the LINQ such that it does not fail when the data is not perfect? And, is there a way to see which part of the LINQ expression is actually failing (I'm guessing that it is due to the missing `<FOLDER>` nodes but that could be wrong and is an ugly brute force way to troubleshoot).

Here is one `<DOCUMENT>` that DOES contain the proper `<FOLDER>` node (at the very bottom):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DOCUMENTCOLLECTION>
<DOCUMENT>
<FILE filename="P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2\ConverterOutput\B0000002\3rd Party CON\D003694452.0001.tif" 
      outputpath="P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2\ConverterOutput\B0000002\3rd Party CON"/>
<ANNOTATION filename=""/>
<INDEX name="Access Level(idmAccessLevel)" value="Admin"/>
<INDEX name="Added By Group(idmAddedByGroup)" value="General Users"/>
<INDEX name="Added By User(idmDocOwner)" value="Import"/>
<INDEX name="Allow Secondary Version Lines?(idmDocVariants)" value="Yes"/>
<INDEX name="Application(idmVerApplication)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Archive Category(idmDocDispCategory)" value="Archive"/>
<INDEX name="Archive Date(idmVerDispDate)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Archive Repository(idmVerDispId)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="ArchivedDocument" value="NO"/>
<INDEX name="Availability Status(idmVerAvailStat)" value="Online"/>
<INDEX name="CAN(idmDocCustom4)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Checked In By Group(idmVerCheckinGroup)" value="General Users"/>
<INDEX name="Checked In By User(idmVerCheckinUser)" value="Import"/>
<INDEX name="Checked Out?(idmVerCheckoutPending)" value="No"/>
<INDEX name="Checkin Date(idmVerCreateDate)" value="3/9/2001 9:20:38 AM"/>
<INDEX name="Child Count(idmVerCD)" value="0"/>
<INDEX name="Comment(idmComment)" value="1983\06_June_Meeting"/>
<INDEX name="Comment(idmVerComment)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Content Search Repository(idmVerCsiId)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Current Content Srch Repository(idmDocCurVerCsiId)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Current Version Author(idmAddedByUser)" value="Import"/>
<INDEX name="Current Version Checked Out?(idmDocCurVerCheckedOut)" value="No"/>
<INDEX name="Current Version Date(idmDocCurVerDate)" value="3/9/2001 9:20:38 AM"/>
<INDEX name="Current Version ID(idmDocCurVerNum)" value="1"/>
<INDEX name="Current Version Index ID(idmDocCurVerCsiCid)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Date Added(idmDateAdded)" value="3/9/2001 9:20:37 AM"/>
<INDEX name="Default Index Versions?(idmDocCsiDefault)" value="No"/>
<INDEX name="DiagnosticID(idmDocCustom5)" value="2-16.MDB-00015"/>
<INDEX name="Document Class(idmDocType)" value="3rd Party CON"/>
<INDEX name="Encrypted File Name(idmVerShelfFileId)" value="_276no__.__1"/>
<INDEX name="ExternalDocument" value="NO"/>
<INDEX name="File Name" value="51099.TIF"/>
<INDEX name="File Name(idmVerFileName)" value="51099.TIF"/>
<INDEX name="File Size(idmVerFileSize)" value="1166770"/>
<INDEX name="Has Annotations?(idmAnnotation)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Index ID(idmVerCsiCid)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Indexed Version Limit(idmDocCsiLimit)" value="1"/>
<INDEX name="Indexing Status(idmVerCsiStatus)" value="Not Indexed"/>
<INDEX name="Item ID(idmId)" value="003694452"/>
<INDEX name="Item ID(idmVerDocId)" value="003694452"/>
<INDEX name="Keyword(idmDocKeywords)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Last Access Date(idmDateAccessed)" value="11/28/2003 3:05:30 PM"/>
<INDEX name="Last Access Date(idmDateModified)" value="8/24/2011 5:52:34 PM"/>
<INDEX name="Last Access Group(idmVerLastGroup)" value="Administrators"/>
<INDEX name="Last Access User(idmModifiedByUser)" value="Admin"/>
<INDEX name="Last Accessed Version(idmDocLastVerId)" value="1"/>
<INDEX name="Latest Version?(idmVerBranchCurVer)" value="Yes"/>
<INDEX name="Merge-Destination Version ID(idmVerMergeDst)" value="0"/>
<INDEX name="Merge-Source Version ID(idmVerMergeSrc)" value="0"/>
<INDEX name="MimeType" value="image/tiff"/>
<INDEX name="Min Item Delete Access Level(idmDocDeleteAccess)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Modification Date(idmVerFileDate)" value="12/19/2000 11:12:30 AM"/>
<INDEX name="Number of Indexed Versions(idmDocCsiCount)" value="0"/>
<INDEX name="Offline Location(idmVerOfflineLocation)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Online Disk Space(idmDocOnlineSize)" value="1166770"/>
<INDEX name="Online Limit(idmDocOnlineLimit)" value="5"/>
<INDEX name="Online Version Count(idmDocOnlineCount)" value="1"/>
<INDEX name="Origin ID(idmDocOriginID)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Origin Library(idmDocOriginLibrary)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Original File Name(idmDocOriginalFile)" value="51099.TIF"/>
<INDEX name="Permanent Index?(idmVerCsiPermanent)" value="No"/>
<INDEX name="Permanent Version?(idmVerPermanent)" value="No"/>
<INDEX name="Property ID(idmDocDynPropertyId)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Protected?(idmDocProtected)" value="Yes"/>
<INDEX name="Publishing Status(idmPublish)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Reclaim Pending?(idmVerReclaimPending)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Reclaim Submitted Date(idmVerReclaimDate)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Replica?(idmDocIsReplica)" value="No"/>
<INDEX name="ReplicatedDocument" value="NO"/>
<INDEX name="Secondary Version Line Count(idmVerBranchCount)" value="0"/>
<INDEX name="Source Version Checkout Date(idmVerPrevCheckoutDate)" value=""/>
<INDEX name="Storage Category(idmDocFileCategory)" value="Documents"/>
<INDEX name="Storage Repository(idmVerShelfId)" value="2"/>
<INDEX name="Title(idmName)" value="3rd Party CON Comments"/>
<INDEX name="Version ID(idmVerId)" value="1"/>
<FOLDER name="/NACAIE/1983/06_June_Meeting/NAPNSC"/>
</DOCUMENT>
```

EDIT: solution follows (contains LINQ that fixed this problem when FOLDER node might be missing; use of First() might be dangerous practice as others note but in this case missing FOLDER nodes had to be handled):

```
namespace CBMI.Common
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
    public static string SafeGetAttributeValue(this XElement element, string attribute)
    {
        return (element != null) ?
          (element.Attribute(attribute) != null) ? 
              element.Attribute(attribute).Value : null : null;
    }
}
}
private long processFile(StreamWriter oWriter, string inFileName)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(inFileName);
        List<DocMetaData> docList =
            (from d in xmlDoc.Descendants("DOCUMENT")
             select new DocMetaData
             {
                 File = d.Element("FILE").Attribute("filename").Value
                 ,
                 ItemID = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Item ID(idmId)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
                 ,
                 Comment = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Comment(idmComment)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
                 ,
                 Title = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Title(idmName)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
                 ,
                 DocClass = d.Elements("INDEX")
                    .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Document Class(idmDocType)")
                    .First()
                    .Attribute("value").Value
                 ,
                 Folder = d.Element("FOLDER").SafeGetAttributeValue("name")
             }
            ).ToList<DocMetaData>();
        OutputListToFile(oWriter, docList);
        return docList.LongCount();
    }
```

Comment: There are 237 well-formed DOCUMENT nodes and only 214 of those contain a FOLDER node. In the LINQ expression FOLDER is being selected without a WHERE or a FIRST so I'm not sure the help below calling First() the probable cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always check the given node before trying to select it:

```
Folder = (d.Element("FOLDER") != null) ? (d.Element("FOLDER").Attribute("name") != null)
                                          ? Attribute("name").Value : null
                                       : null
```

But I admit that can get kind of ugly. In that case you can create an XElement extension method that does that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static string SafeGetAttributeValue(this XElement element, string attribute)
   {
      return (element != null) ? (element.Attribute(attribute) != null)
                                              ? Attribute(attribute).Value : null
                                           : null
   }
}
```

Which you could use like:

```
select new DocMetaData
{
   Folder = d.Element("FOLDER").SafeGetAttributeValue("name"),
   //the rest of your object creation
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. The other responders above expressed concerns that .First() could be the problem but I think your answer seems more relevant to my data situation. In this XML file, I have 237 DOCUMENT nodes and only 214 of them contain a FOLDER node which suggests your answer is exactly what I need. Where would I add the Extensions class? I have another referenced project in my solution which is used by my WinForms project - could I put there?

Comment: I added the Extensions class and the compiler complains about ? Attribute(attribute.Value). Red squiggleline is under Attribute and states that 'System.Attribute' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

Comment: I see the problem now. I think this is a little more clear: public static string SafeGetAttributeValue(this XElement element, string attribute)
   {
       if (element == null) return null;
       if (element.Attribute(attribute) == null) return null;
       return element.Attribute(attribute).Value;
   }

Comment: @John Galt -- sorry, I was just able to check back on SO. The Extensions class is just something I added-- you can put that wherever it makes sense to put it-- which it seems like you did. I usually put stuff like that in a Utilities namespace. And yeah, you can totally remove the ternary if it makes it more readable. Hope this helps!

Comment: it sure helped. See bottomMost EDIT in the original post where I pasted my final LINQ code that worked completely because of your insight on how to handle the missing FOLDER nodes with an extension method. Cool...so much more to learn !

Answer (score 1):

I can't test to see if this is the exact problem for you, but `First()` throws an exception if there isn't any values in the query. You can avoid that by using `FirstOrDefault()` instead and then checking if the result is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is to *never* use the `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` methods in the middle of the query.  It should always be the last method that is called.  If you need to select a property from the selected item, project first, then call the method.  It will lead to cleaner looking code making situations like this a whole lot easier to deal with.

e.g.,

```
// Change this:
d.Elements("INDEX")
 .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Comment(idmComment)")
 .First()
 .Attribute("value").Value

// to this:
d.Elements("INDEX")
 .Where(i => i.Attribute("name").Value == "Comment(idmComment)")
 .Select(i => i.Attribute("value").Value)
 .First()
```

I'd rewrite it as this:

```
private long processFile(StreamWriter oWriter, string inFileName)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(inFileName);
    List<DocMetaData> docList = xmlDoc.Descendants("DOCUMENT")
        .Select(e => new
        {
            Folder = (string)e.Element("FOLDER").Attribute("name"),
            File = (string)e.Element("FILE").Attribute("filename"),
            Comment = (string)e.Elements("INDEX")
                .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "Comment(idmComment)")
                .Select(i => (string)i.Attribute("value"))
                .FirstOrDefault(),
            Title = (string)e.Elements("INDEX")
                .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "Title(idmName)")
                .Select(i => (string)i.Attribute("value"))
                .FirstOrDefault(),
            DocClass = (string)e.Elements("INDEX")
                .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "Document Class(idmDocType)")
                .Select(i => (string)i.Attribute("value"))
                .FirstOrDefault(),
        })
        .ToList();
    OutputListToFile(oWriter, docList);
    return docList.LongCount();
}
```

Comment: Just to make it clear about your *never use policy*, if your query contains a subqueries, you wouldn't oppose to using these methods on these subqueries, correct?

Comment: Oh yes of course not.  I'm referring to fluent syntaxes.  I'd never chain anything off of any one of these calls.

Answer (score 0):

In your linq query, on every fields that might be null, hence throwing an exception if you .Value them, you could :

```
MyDone = PossibleNullNode != null ? PossibleNullNode.Value : WhateverFloatsYourBoat
```